# Help with output of post classes using apply_filters

Tags: walker, post-class

I’m new to scripting, this is a plugin I'd like to modify to output post classes.

When I try using: `apply_filters( 'post_class', $page->post_class )` it only outputs `array=" "`. Do I need an additional function to hook into post classes? In my research I can't tell if my syntax is wrong or I'm missing a function to "pull" in the classes for `apply_filters` to grab onto. Thanks a ton for any help.

```
    var $db_fields = array ('parent' => 'post_parent', 'id' => 'ID');


    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='children'>\n";
    }


    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }


    function start_el(&$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        if ( $depth )
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        else
            $indent = '';

        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="item_'.$page->ID.'" '.apply_filters( 'post_class', $page->post_class ).'><span>'.apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ).'</span>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with generous help using join()...

```
function start_el(&$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        if ( $depth )
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        else
            $indent = '';

        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="item_'.$page->ID.'" class="'.join( " ", get_post_class( "", $page->ID )).'"><span>'.apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ).'</span>';
    }
```